# Deleting entire directories using azure blob storage api

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using the Azure object store in the following manner:

I have one container, and beneath it many blobs in a directory structure.

I am using Azure Blob Storage api to manage it.

- Is there a way to delete an entire directory?
- Do I really need to list all the blobs under it and then delete them one by one?
- Is there a workaround like deleting all blobs with the same uri prefix (again, without listing them and then deleting them one by one)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a new solution, but we did that using https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx - if we see what is going on with Fiddler, there are only prefix-ed blobs returned. Please see if that will work for you:

```
static void GetBlobsByPrefix(string Container, string Prefix)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Prefix))
        {
            var _Container = GetBlobContainer(Container);
            var _Blobs = _Container.ListBlobs(Prefix, true);
            foreach (IListBlobItem blob in _Blobs)
            {

                 ....
            }
        }
    }

    static CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(string container)
    {           

        CloudStorageAccount _StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("rus_AzureStorageConnectionString"));

        CloudBlobClient _BlobClient = _StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer _Container = _BlobClient.GetContainerReference(container);
        return _Container;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for a solution that didn't involve listing the blobs and then going over them and delete them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the container and all your blobs will be deleted. Containers on Azure Storage act as a "folder" for your blobs.

Comment: In our current structure in the storage, there is only one container and I don't want to delete all the folders under it. before changing the structure and making each main folder a container, I wanted to be sure there is currently no way to delete all the blobs in the folder in a scalable way (or at least moving the responsibility for the efficient deletion to azure).